# How to include multiple images inside a TikZ loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, loops

I have a case, where my files are named `images_001.png` .... `images_011.png`.

I tried to put them like this:

```
\def\filelists{1/{"t0_01"},2/{"038"}, 3/{"050"},4/{"060"}}

\foreach \i\element in \filelists {

\node[inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] at (0, 1.5+\i*-3.1){\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=3cm,bb=390bp 70bp 3810bp 930bp,clip]{/Users/xxxxx/paper_animations/fig4_conc_set3_\element.png}};

}
```

but I could not manage finally. Any advice?

Comment: Does it work if you put a `/` (*forward* slash) between `\i` and `\element`?  If not, it would help greatly to expand your example to make it a full document, and to describe the actual error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the `\includegraphics` macro only expands its path argument once, so you need to preprocess it and feed the fully expanded path to it:

```
\def\filelists{1/{"t0_01"},2/{"038"}, 3/{"050"},4/{"060"}}

  \foreach \i/\element in \filelists {
    \edef\imagepath{/Users/xxxxx/paper_animations/fig4_conc_set3_\element.png}
    \node[inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] at (0, 1.5+\i*-3.1){\includegraphics[width=12cm,   height=3cm,bb=390bp 70bp 3810bp 930bp,clip]{\imagepath}};
}
```

If this doesn't work try:

```
\def\filelists{1/{"t0_01"},2/{"038"}, 3/{"050"},4/{"060"}}

  \foreach \i/\element in \filelists {
    \node[inner sep=0cm, outer sep=0cm] at (0, 1.5+\i*-3.1){%
    \edef\imagecmd{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=3cm,bb=390bp 70bp 3810bp 930bp,clip]{/Users/xxxxx/paper_animations/fig4_conc_set3_\element.png}}\imagecmd};
}
```

which should work.

As Matthew already commented: There is a `/` missing between `\i` and `\element`.